# If Statement Code Issue

Tags: java, if-statement

I was given the following code by my prof.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer customer;
    Transaction transaction;
    double withdrawalAmount = 0;

    boolean finished = false;

    while (finished == false)
    {
        // Menu Display and Get user input
        int inputInt = 0;
        while (inputInt == 0)
        {
            inputInt = displayMenuAndGetInput();

                    // if the input is out of range
                    if ((inputInt < 1) || (inputInt > 8))
                    {
                            System.out.println("\nThe input is out of range!");
                            System.out.println();
                            inputInt = 0;
                    }
            } //end while

            // switch to correspondence function
            switch (inputInt)

            {
                case 1:
                    customer = createPersonalCustomer();
                    System.out.println("\nThe Personal customer has been created: \n" + newPC.toString());
                    customers.add(customer);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    customer = createCommercialCustomer();
                    System.out.println("\nThe Commercial customer has been created: \n" + newCC.toString());
                    customers.add(customer);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    transaction = recordTransaction();
                    if(transaction != null)
                        System.out.println("\nThe Transaction has been created: \n" + trans.toString());
                    else
                        System.out.println("\nThe ID could not be found.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    withdrawalAmount = makeWithdrawal();
                    if(withdrawalAmount > 0)
                        System.out.println("\nAmount withdrawn from this account: " + moneyFormat.format(acct.getMakeWithdrawal()) + "\n");
                    else
                        System.out.println("\nThe ID could not be found.");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    displayCustomer();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    displayCustomerSummary();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    displayGrandSummary();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    // exit
                    finished = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");

                    break;
            } // end switch
    } // end while

}
```

I am supposed take the following code

```
// Create a new Transaction
public static Transaction recordTransaction(){}
```

and make a loop that works in the following scenario:

the customer id is entered, and if the customer id is not matched in the array, the error read out in case 3 is generated and the main menu is displayed. If the customer id is valid, the user enters the input info below.

Below is my code

```
public static Transaction recordTransaction(){

System.out.println("Enter the customer ID to create the transaction > ");
    long customerID = scan.nextLong();

    for (Customer c : customers) {
        if (c.getCustomerID() == customerID) {
            if (trans != null) {

            System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of gold > ");
                Transaction.goldWt = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of platinum > ");
                Transaction.platinumWt = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of silver > ");
                Transaction.silverWt = scan.nextDouble();
                }
        }
            return null; 
}
```

Anywho, I've run this a number of ways and either my code will accept an invalid and valid customer ID, or it will not accept an invalid or valid customer id.
 I know I am probably overlooking something and that is why I am desperately requesting the help of the forum. I have OCD tendencies when it comes to programming and this is my first intro java class so I am not well versed in the language. I have been stuck on this issue for the last two days. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to instantiate a `new Transaction()` within the method `recordTransaction()` and return it when appropriate.

```
public static Transaction recordTransaction(){

    System.out.println("Enter the customer ID to create the transaction > "); long customerID = scan.nextLong();

    for (Customer c : customers) {
        if (c.getCustomerID() == customerID) {
            Transaction trans = new Transaction();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of gold > ");
            trans.goldWt = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of platinum > ");
            trans.platinumWt = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("\nEnter the weight of silver > ");
            trans.silverWt = scan.nextDouble();

            return trans;
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. I was under the impression since I already called trans before, I did not have to call it again.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "accepting". Does "accepting nothing" mean you get the message "The ID could not be found." whatever the customer id you provide?<br/> You should provide with the code for the method createPersonalCustomer().

Comment: Yes, the output states: "The ID could not be found." for any ID that provide. I don't follow on your second statement "You should provide with the code for the method createPersonalCustomer()."

Comment: We don't know what is in `createPersonalCustomer()`. Maybe that is where the problem is located. The customer id might be erroneous. Or too many fields are declared as `static` as it seems you are not very comfortable with the concept.

Comment: I think the problem lies with my array. that static "issue" I was having was trying to get the code I was provided to work.

Comment: So I figured out the problem. We are supposed to have the customerID =Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()/1000; This is messing up my program. If I have the customerID = a set number  like 3 then everything works. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks about your code:

```
if (trans != null) {
```

What is "trans"? I guess it must refer to a Transaction instance.

```
Transaction.goldWt = ...
```

Shouldn't that be "trans.goldWt"? (and the same for plantinum and silver, of course). If it's really `Transaction.goldWt` then you are always changing that single value.

```
return null;
```

you never return anything so the calling code always goes to "no ID". Shouldn't you "`return trans`"?

Comment: I'll just note that if the code currently compiles, then `goldWt` is static, meaning there's only 1 variable for all the classes of type `Transaction` and that it probably shouldn't be static.

Comment: Hmm, the issue was with my getter and setter for my customerID;

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being generated by the getter and setter method for the random customerID for each account being created.

Thank you 
Merci!